# drag and drop system overlapping dropped divs element

Tags: javascript, css

try dropping the grey boxes inside any column if you drop too many inside on column, the boxes will end up overlapping with eachother. How can I do a validation to stop this from happening? I want each box to be underneath eachother with a X px gap from eachother.

Below is not the entire code for those boxes. if you would like to see the full source code please use the website.

```js
function dragInfo(event) {
    event.dataTransfer.setData("Info", event.target.id);
}


function allowDrop(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
}

function drop(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var data = event.dataTransfer.getData("Info");
    event.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    console.log(data);
}

function drag_drop(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

```css
.columnContent {
    padding-top: 5px;
    width: 129px;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 3px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    flex-direction: column;
}


.dropBox {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    height: 140px;
    width: 120px;
    border: 2px dashed;
    background-color: lightgray;
    cursor: move;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
    <div class="columnContent" id="c1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
        <p>Customer's order</p>
        <div class="dropBox" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ondragstart="dragInfo(event)" id="dp1" draggable="true">
            <p id="para1">Drag file here</p>
            <div class="leftAlign">
                <img src="pdf.jpg" id="pdfImg" style="visibility: hidden">
                <p1 id="pdfInfo"></p1>
                <br>
            </div>
            <input id="txt1" placeholder="Customer's code" style="visibility: hidden">
            <br>
            <input id="txt2" placeholder="Customer's size" style="visibility: hidden">
            <br>
            <input id="txt3" placeholder="Customer's DD" style="visibility: hidden">
            <br>
            <button id="btn" style="visibility: hidden">Save</button>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="columnContent" id="c2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <p>Planned</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the HTML code to this:

```html
<div class="columnContent" id="c2" ondrop="drop(event, this)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <p>Planned</p>
</div>
```

Passing `this` as the second parameter to the `drop` function.

Then change the JavaScript to the following:

```js
function drop(event, el) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var data = event.dataTransfer.getData("Info");
    el.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    console.log(data);
}
```

Adding the option for an element as the second parameter. Then use the passed element as the element to be appended.

---

#### Full snippet below

```js
function dragInfo(event) {
    event.dataTransfer.setData("Info", event.target.id);
}

function allowDrop(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
}

function drop(event, el) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var data = event.dataTransfer.getData("Info");
    el.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    console.log(data);
}

function drag_drop(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

```css
.columnContent {
    padding-top: 5px;
    width: 129px;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 3px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.dropBox {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    height: 140px;
    width: 120px;
    border: 2px dashed;
    background-color: lightgray;
    cursor: move;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
    <div class="columnContent" id="c1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
        <p>Customer's order</p>
        <div class="dropBox" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ondragstart="dragInfo(event)" id="dp1" draggable="true">
            <p id="para1">Drag file here</p>
            <div class="leftAlign">
                <img src="pdf.jpg" id="pdfImg" style="visibility: hidden">
                <p1 id="pdfInfo"></p1>
                <br>
            </div>
            <input id="txt1" placeholder="Customer's code" style="visibility: hidden">
            <br>
            <input id="txt2" placeholder="Customer's size" style="visibility: hidden">
            <br>
            <input id="txt3" placeholder="Customer's DD" style="visibility: hidden">
            <br>
            <button id="btn" style="visibility: hidden">Save</button>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="columnContent" id="c2" ondrop="drop(event, this)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <p>Planned</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you that did fix the problem!

Comment: what is "this" passing?

Comment: you need to pass the current scope, for that u need to pass 'this'

Comment: Im getting a new error now which I think its involving passing the parameter this. dropping many boxes to the column will eventually cause one of the column to transform into dragable child. Have a look! http://2much.online/ drop several boxes around and you shall get an error where you can drag and drop one of the columns as you try to drag the box the column will come with it.